# Unable to access shared Glue table from Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, aws-glue, aws-lake-formation

I am using a Jupyter notebook to read data from a shared Glue table (using LakeFormation). I am using the `awswrangler` library. I am able to read a test table from a sample database. Note the `local_db` database mentioned below is locally created in the same AWS account in which I am running this query. The `lf_shared_table` table is the resource link to the shared table.

```
import awswrangler as wr
df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(sql="SELECT * FROM lf_shared_table", database="local_db")
```

Error

```
~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awswrangler/_config.py in wrapper(*args_raw, **kwargs)
    437                 del args[name]
    438                 args = {**args, **keywords}
--> 439         return function(**args)
    440 
    441     wrapper.__doc__ = _inject_config_doc(doc=function.__doc__, available_configs=available_configs)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awswrangler/athena/_read.py in read_sql_query(sql, database, ctas_approach, categories, chunksize, s3_output, workgroup, encryption, kms_key, keep_files, ctas_database_name, ctas_temp_table_name, ctas_bucketing_info, use_threads, boto3_session, max_cache_seconds, max_cache_query_inspections, max_remote_cache_entries, max_local_cache_entries, data_source, params, s3_additional_kwargs, pyarrow_additional_kwargs)
    878         s3_additional_kwargs=s3_additional_kwargs,
    879         boto3_session=session,
--> 880         pyarrow_additional_kwargs=pyarrow_additional_kwargs,
    881     )
    882 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awswrangler/athena/_read.py in _resolve_query_without_cache(sql, database, data_source, ctas_approach, categories, chunksize, s3_output, workgroup, encryption, kms_key, keep_files, ctas_database_name, ctas_temp_table_name, ctas_bucketing_info, use_threads, s3_additional_kwargs, boto3_session, pyarrow_additional_kwargs)
    593         use_threads=use_threads,
    594         s3_additional_kwargs=s3_additional_kwargs,
--> 595         boto3_session=boto3_session,
    596     )
    597 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awswrangler/athena/_read.py in _resolve_query_without_cache_regular(sql, database, data_source, s3_output, keep_files, chunksize, categories, encryption, workgroup, kms_key, wg_config, use_threads, s3_additional_kwargs, boto3_session)
    508         boto3_session=boto3_session,
    509         categories=categories,
--> 510         metadata_cache_manager=_cache_manager,
    511     )
    512     return _fetch_csv_result(

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awswrangler/athena/_utils.py in _get_query_metadata(query_execution_id, boto3_session, categories, query_execution_payload, metadata_cache_manager)
    259         _query_execution_payload: Dict[str, Any] = query_execution_payload
    260     else:
--> 261         _query_execution_payload = wait_query(query_execution_id=query_execution_id, boto3_session=boto3_session)
    262     cols_types: Dict[str, str] = get_query_columns_types(
    263         query_execution_id=query_execution_id, boto3_session=boto3_session

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awswrangler/athena/_utils.py in wait_query(query_execution_id, boto3_session)
    795     _logger.debug("StateChangeReason: %s", response["Status"].get("StateChangeReason"))
    796     if state == "FAILED":
--> 797         raise exceptions.QueryFailed(response["Status"].get("StateChangeReason"))
    798     if state == "CANCELLED":
    799         raise exceptions.QueryCancelled(response["Status"].get("StateChangeReason"))

QueryFailed: HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: Required Table Storage Descriptor is not populated. (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same error when querying shared tables. We had missing AWS LakeFormation Permissions. Adding `lakeformation:GetDataAccess` to the IAM Role (besides glue and s3 permissions) resolved this. Long form:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Lakeformation",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                 "lakeformation:GetDataAccess",
                 "lakeformation:GrantPermissions"
             ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure why this is necessary but I believe that the Access to Glue Data Catalog (Hive Metastore) is given through Lake Formation. When the athena connector cannot access the metadata it throws this somewhat misleading error message. I was searching the problem with the glue permissions for too long.

Some more Background can be found in the [AWS Lake Formation Data Access doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/access-control-underlying-data.html).